# wrong paths on multi website magento install

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, wamp, httpd.conf

I am running a magento 1.7.0.2 instance with WAMP 2.1 on Windows 7. My goal is to set up one magento store, and one
I followed the tutorial described [here](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/) and I setup website *profi* on a subdirectory, but when I accessed the frontend on `http://localhost/profi/` the first thing I noticed that the images paths were broken.

Broken: `http://localhost/bms/profi/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo.gif`

Correct:
`http://localhost/bms/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo.gif`

This is the same for the JS & CSS files. I've made the following modifications to the index.php  file in the *profi* folder:

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../../app/Mage.php';
```

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'profi';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```

Answer (score 4):

It was a matter of configuring the second website's URLs.

I went to System > Configuration > General > Web > Unsecure. The Base URL was `http://localhost/profi/` and I added ../ to the following the following:

- Base Skin URL: `{{unsecure_base_url}}../skin/`
- Base Media URL: `{{unsecure_base_url}}../media/`
- Base JavaScript URL: `{{unsecure_base_url}}../media/`

That did the trick. I see on the frontend everything looks in order. Hope I won't run into anymore problems with this set-up.